# Using Non-REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My question should be pretty simple, is there a way to do standard WooCommerce stuff without using the *REST* API? Using a direct API through a PHP class will do just fine, and obviously all the functionality I want does exist after loading up the entire WordPress system, but I'm trying to do this from my own isolated script, so I'd rather know the simplest way to include the actual core WooCommerce classes and use them directly. I'm unable to identify which classes I would need to include for this though.

I just want standard functionality for adding to and modifying the catalogue really. I was able to do this with the *REST* API but it didn't seem to provide a way for me to find products by SKU which is important. Finding help on this is hard due to the fact all results are usually focused on the REST API.

What's the simplest way to start using the core *non-REST* WooCommerce API?

Comment: Hi! Have you tried using the non-REST API in the `woocommerce/includes/api/legacy` folder? The problem I see, though, is the *legacy* in the path, which smells of deprecated. FYI, I am discussing a similar issue in this question => http://stackoverflow.com/q/42056804/2972183