# new WP_REST_Request(PUT)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to update products or products variations (price of variation, description of variation, quantity of variation product).
I tried many methods found online, but with no luck. Some days ago i found the info [What WooCommerce API should I use on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056804/what-woocommerce-api-should-i-use-on-the-server)

But it works on geting info or creating a new product (simple).

Do anyone of you know how can it be modified and used as a updating script for products or product variation?

```
>>>>/* Load WordPress */
require('wp-load.php');

>/* Create an API controller */
$api = new WC_REST_Products_Controller();

>/* Build the request to create a new product */
$request = new WP_REST_Request ('POST', '', '');
$request->set_body_params( array (
    'name' => 'New Product',
    'slug' => 'new-product',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'status' => 'publish',
    'regular_price' => 60,
    'sale_price' => 40,
));

>/* Execute the request */
$response = $api->create_item( $request );

>/* Print to screen the response from the API */
print_r( $response );
```

Thanks. Really thanks